# In which comic did Spider-Man remove his mask to a little girl?

Tags: story-identification, comics, spider-man

I'm looking for a comic where Spider-Man removes his mask to smile at a little girl.  The art is realistic. Seemed pretty much like a panel from Alex Ross.

The girl in this snippet says something to herself, something like that Peter's face "looked like the most common face she ever saw", I think is from the *Spectacular Spider-Man* but don't know what number.

Answer (score 12):

I recognised this premise from the 1990s cartoon episode [Make a Wish](https://spiderman-animated.fandom.com/wiki/Make_a_Wish) and [Attack of the Octobot](https://spiderman-animated.fandom.com/wiki/Attack_of_the_Octobot).

> This episode [Attack of the Octobot] and Make a Wish are based on a combination of two different storylines from The Amazing Spider-Man comics which are The Amazing Spider-Man #55 - 56 (December, 1967 - January, 1968) and The Amazing Spider-Man #248 (January, 1984).
> [...]
> In The Amazing Spider-Man #248, which is titled The Kid Who Collects Spider-Man!, Spider-Man visits a young boy named Timmy Harrison who idolizes him. At the end of the story Spider-Man reveals to Timmy his secret identity and you learn that Timmy is dying of leukemia and only has a few weeks left to live.

So the comic where he takes off his mask to a child is 'The Amazing Spider-Man #248', however it is only in the cartoon that the child is a girl.

Neither episode has a line about Peter Parker having a common face though, but [somebody in chat found the panels for me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60260838#60260838):

[image: The Amazing Spider-Man #248, page 9]

> **Spider-Man**: Now Tim, you know that's my greatest secret. If people knew who was under this mask. I'd never know a moment's peace. All of my friends would live in constant danger
> **Tim**: I know... But I'd never tell another soul that I knew... Long as I lived.. Honest!
> **Spider-Man**: I believe you Tim, but I can't --! I...
> *Spider-Man walks to the window, then returns to Tim's bed and removes his mask*
> **Spider-Man**: Tim... My name is Peter Parker. I took most of the photos from the articles you saved.

[image: The Amazing Spider-Man #248, page 10]

> **Tim**: You mean all these years, 'ol man Jameson has been paying you to take pictures of yourself?
> **Spider-Man**: Uh-Huh
> **Tim**: Boy that's great, I wish we could tell him!
> **Spider-Man**: I know, I do to... But we can't! You mustn't even tell anyone I was here!
> **Tim**: Don't worry Pete. I understand. It's our secret. Forever and ever I promise.
> **Spider-Man**: Yeah. I guess that makes us best buddies then!
> **Tim**: You bet Pete. Buddies to the end.
> **Spider-Man**: Hey... It's really... getting late now! I have to get moving, and you have to get some sleep.
> **Tim**: Okay g'night Pete!
> **Spider-Man**: Take  are of yourself, Tim.

Comment: How does anyone recognize Peter Parker, especially by his face? "Wow. You're some random high school or college student!"

Comment: Thanks fot the reply to everyone! I found the comic, the line of the kid wasn't 'common face', the line was sad: 'Saddest face I ever saw'
The comic was Spectacular Spiderman Vol 2. #14

Comment: @Javier2004 you can answer your own question, and use [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7vTg.jpg). I'll even add the alt text for you if you can't.

Comment: @Laurel That's [exactly what happens](https://imgur.com/a/TReIsv2) in _Ultimate Spider-Man_ v1 No. 10, when the Kingpin unmasks the just-starting out superhero. Admttedly, not the main continuity.